# Read live Values from one Excel Workbook to another Workbook while opened

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I would like to be able to read and write values using VBA from one OPEN Excel workbook to another application without using the "as worksheet" function due to this being a non-windows application. Is this possible?

The code I've posted is from a PLC application using scripting.

I just need to know what function to use besides `.open` since the file is already opened.

```
Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs1, objXLWs2, objXLWs5

Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objXLApp.Visible = True

Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("File.xlsm")
'~~> Working with Sheet1
Set objXLWs1 = objXLWb.Sheets(1)
Set objXLWs2 = objXLWb.Sheets(2)
Set objXLWs5 = objXLWb.Sheets(5)

'~~>Write SetPoints to Sheet1
With objXLWs1

 '~~>Write 

 .Cells(6,23).value = SmartTags("Job Time Sec to OEE")
 .Cells(6,23).value = SmartTags("Run Time Sec to OEE")


End With

''~~>Write Setup Values to Sheet2

'~~> Save as Excel File (xls) to retain format
objXLWb.Save

objXLWb.Close (False)

Set objXLWs1 = Nothing
Set objXLWs2 = Nothing
Set objXLWs5 = Nothing
Set objXLWb = Nothing

objXLApp.Quit
Set objXLApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

If the workbook is already open you can just refer to it by name as part of the `Workbooks` collection.
`Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks("File.xlsm")`

Edit: Since you have changed your question I'm no longer certain what you're asking. My guess is that your 'already open' workbook isn't open in the same Excel instance you're creating with `Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, so you'll need a reference to the *existing* Excel application, then the open workbook within that application.

Comment: Very fast response. This didn't work. There is a window that pops up and immediately goes away & the data doesn't get written to the excel sheet.

Comment: I will post the whole script today, this might give more of an insight.

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion. I'm no expert on scripting by any means. So if I was working with an already opened excel sheet, I do not need to create an object. Could I leave this out & change open to Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks("File.xlsm")  & try the script?

Comment: I don't have any experience with PLC Applications. In Excel VBA, as long as the workbook is already open in the same application-instance, `Set objXLWb = Workbooks("File.xlsm")` will get you a variable representing the workbook. Your `objXLApp` is referencing a brand-new instance of Excel though (since you use `CreateObject`), so it won't have your workbook in its `Workbooks` collection.